# Modify django action style

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

This's default action style.

```
<select>
  <option>
    <button />
  </option>
  <option>
    <button />
  </option>
  <option>
    <button />
  </option>
</select>
```

How shoul change it style to button, like this right part:

[image]

```
<div class="gap-2">
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

I know it default rendering to `<select>`, but i wanted to rendering to each `<button>`.
I tried custom ModelAdmin `def get_action_choices` but not succcess
What should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

The template that renders the action bar is located at [**`django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/actions.html`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d9b91e38361696014bdc98434d6d018eae809519/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/actions.html). You can override this template by [enabling `APP_DIRS` <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory), and then thus write a file at any app with **`app_name/templates/admin/actions.html`**. As you can see in the GitHub link however, the action bar is not that simple: the main blocks that are interesting are:

> ```
> {% for field in action_form %}{% if field.label %}<label>{{ field.label }} {{ field }}</label>{% else %}{{ field }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
> {% endblock %}
> {% block actions-submit %}
> <button type="submit" class="button" title="{% translate "Run the selected action" %}" name="index" value="{{ action_index|default:0 }}">{% translate "Go" %}</b\utton\>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

The first one thus lists the label of the action forms. That action form will by default contain only one field: a selection field of the different options.

It thus might make more sense to try to plug in a different action form that does not create a `<select>` field, but thus lists different fields as buttons.

You will also have to make sure that you make a POST request, which includes all selected checkboxes.

Comment: I tried to replace the <label> tag with <button> but got an error. Can you give more details of the code after the change?

Comment: @HappyKoala: the labels are *not* the action options, the form has actually one field, which is a `select` field, so that field contains the options.

Comment: But I still don't know how to change the rendering tag from `<select><option>` to `<button>` of the action

Comment: @HappyKoala: you inject a different `action_form` with a different form field and widget.

Comment: I finally gave up on the rewrite approach, it was time-consuming and I didn't think it would work with the current development style. I decided to use restframework and a separate front-end project to implement custom interactions. Thank you for help @willeM_ Van Onsem